# Quartz Reschedule job trigger

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am new to java and trying to learn quartz. I have main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {

    try {
        JobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.newJob(Job1.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();

        Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("cronTrigger1", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.weeklyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(3, 12, 38)).build();

        Scheduler scheduler1 = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler1.start();
        scheduler1.scheduleJob(job1, trigger1);

 scheduler1.shutdown();
}

    catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Which works fine. It prints to the console on 3rd day of the week at 12:38 pm. 
Now, what I want to do is to reschedule the trigger, so that it deletes the previous stored trigger and creates a new trigger with new schedule.

I read a lot of things at a lot of places but I just can't seem to understand clearly what I actually have to do, for ex:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
Trigger newTigger = what ever you want;
Trigger oldTrigger = context.getTrigger()
Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);
}
```

and also this:

```
// Define a new Trigger  
Trigger trigger = newTrigger() 
.withIdentity("newTrigger", "group1") 
.startNow() 
.build(); 
// tell the scheduler to remove the old trigger with the given key, and 
// put the new one in its place 
sched.rescheduleJob(triggerKey("oldTrigger", "group1"), trigger);
```

but I can't understand the approach(I do understand what is happening in the code though). Thanks in advance.

Comment: So , your question is ?

Comment: @KenChan how to reschedule by creating a new trigger and removing the old one

Comment: the code that you post in the question should do it , it is `scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);` .

Comment: @KenChan yes but since I have a big application, and I am selecting time from webpage, what should I do to reschedule from the webpage itself? shall I post another question giving the details of what I have done by far?